# Python - Making a script that changes Django settings

Tags: python, settings

I have a django project with 3 completely different templates, each with its own folder. 
Would it be possibile to make a python script that changes django's settings ( file paths to static files and templates ) when executed ?

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or give me advice on how would I go about achieving this on my own ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why not use multiple settings files? You can have a base_settings.py which has common settings and then separate files with the settings that you want. After that, you would just import everything from the desired settings file into base_settings.py. You could even take it further and make it import a specific file based on an ENV variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
settings.py
```

You can have a structure like this:

```
settings/
  base.py
  development.py
  staging.py
  production.py
```

---

`base.py` contains all the common settings.

---

`development.py` imports all the settings from `base.py` and overwrites necessary settings for the `development server` something like this:

```
from your_app.settings.base import *

A_SETTING_TO_CHANGE = DIFFERENT_VALUE_FOR_DEVELOPMENT
```

---

`staging.py` imports all the settings from `base.py` and overwrites necessary settings for the `staging server` something like this:

```
from your_app.settings.base import *

A_SETTING_TO_CHANGE = DIFFERENT_VALUE_FOR_STAGING
```

---

`production.py` imports all the settings from `base.py` and overwrites necessary settings for the `production server` something like this:

```
from your_app.settings.base import *

A_SETTING_TO_CHANGE = DIFFERENT_VALUE_FOR_PRODUCTION
```

---

Then in `wsgi.py` and `manage.py` change:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_app.settings')
```

To:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'your_app.settings.development')
```

---

- In the `staging server`, set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to `'your_app.settings.staging'`.
- In the `production server`, set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to `'your_app.settings.production'`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using a non-version controlled local_settings.py file (which is imported into settings.py and overrides values) is outlined in this post:

https://agileleaf.com/blog/a-better-way-to-manage-settings-py-in-your-django-projects/amp/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31135859)